# Remove value from String which is comma separated

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am very new to java and was currently having the below requirement.

Whenever i found `12.1` in a string it should be removed but it is conditional. for Eg Below

`12.1,ztel,presto` should be `ztel,presto`

`12.1` should be replaced as `blank`

`12.1/7.1` should not do anything as it is separate value

I tried doing `stringValue.replace("12.1","");`

Mostly the requirement is if `12.1` is found comma separated or only `12.1` it should be replaced as blank else not.

The above code was working partially and not working for all conditions.

Please guide and help me learn. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your requirements are not very clear. I think you're slightly suffering from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please specify what _problem_ you're trying to solve. I assume that you have some sequence of comma-separated values and you want to drop all values equal to `12.1` from it.

Comment: @yeputons : i have mentioned the conditions. 12.1 should be replaced by blank when the value appears comma separated or when it is 12.1 else it should not

Comment: use this `stringValue.replaceAll("(12.1,)|(12.1)", "");`

Comment: @Baby, the `.` is any character and not a period.

Comment: @matt haha ok need to escape it `"(12\\.1,)|(12\\.1)"`

Comment: @Baby : stringValue.replaceAll("(12.1,)|(12.1)", ""); is not working for when the string value is 12.1/7.1 that time the output is  /7.1

Comment: What can follow 12.1? eg. "12\\.1,?[^/]" would leave on the case you just suggested.

Comment: You should really consider parsing it into separate values, eg. `String[] values = line.split("\\t");` Then putting them back together with comma's afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `12.1` that  should be replaced as blank is the only word in that string you can use this:

```
stringValue.replaceAll("^12\\.1$","blank");
```

then replace again that string with this to replace the one separated with coma:

```
stringValue.replaceAll("12\\.1,","");
```

the final code will be like this :

```
stringValue= stringValue.replaceAll("^12\\.1$","blank").replaceAll("12\\.1,","");
```

note: ^ mean start of line while $ mean end of a line

Comment: I get the below error Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: Wow thats awesome. Perfect answer ... Thats what i wanted. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this  stringValue.replace( "12.1," , "");
Use comma after 12.7 in the first parameter.

Comment: what if in the case String value="12.1"; That time this condition will fail.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `String.replaceAll` is a regex. Did you consider,

```
yourString.replaceAll("12\\.1,?", "");
```

Now it will only use `.` and not "any character" as a `.` would do. It also will match the comma, if present.

If you cannot have it followed by something specific, you can use a negation.

```
yourString.replaceAll("12\\.1,?[^/]", "");
```

That would leave `12.1/7.1`.

Comment: `String.replace` doesnt take `regex` as a parameter. `String.replaceAll` does

Comment: @matt it breaks when the value is 12.1/5.7. the output is coming /5.7

Comment: @NitheshKumar I edited it to include a way to pass 12.1/5.7, it is difficult to know your exact criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use case for a regex! You can try out different regular expressions to match your data at [regexr](http://regexr.com).

I would start with something like

```
^[\d\.]+,?
```

- Start of a line: `^`
- Group `[]` containing digits `\d` or dots `\.` (you have to escape since `.` is a special character)
- One or more of these `+`
- An optional comma `,?`

You'll need to do something about not matching an entry containing a slash `/` - I'm not sure how to handle that.